# Use semicolon in global-set-key for function in .emacs

Tags: emacs, elisp

I am trying to set [Ctrl]-[;] as a keybinding in my .emacs like this

```
(global-set-key "\C-;" 'comment-or-uncomment-region)
```

however it doesn't work when I try (i don't get any error messages, it just has no effect). It will work though if i try a normal character (such as setting it to "\C-p").

I have also tried

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C-;") 'comment-or-uncomment-region)
```

but I don't like this option because for me it doesn't work when i run "emacs -nw".  Any thoughts on how I can do this?

EDIT:
When I run <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>c</kbd><kbd>C-;</kbd> in `emacs -nw` I get the output:

```
; runs the command self-insert-command
```

which is exactly the same as when I run <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>c</kbd><kbd>;</kbd> in `emacs -nw`

So I believe phils is right, that it is a terminal problem, because emacs never actually sees <kbd>C-;</kbd>, it only sees <kbd>;</kbd>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `(kbd "C-;")` is absolutely fine and correct.

I suspect when you type <kbd>C-;</kbd> when running `emacs -nw`, your terminal is not actually sending anything to Emacs.

So your problem is more likely to be a question of how to get your terminal to send <kbd>C-;</kbd> to Emacs (or alternatively how to get Emacs to recognise the sequence which *is* sent).

If you run `emacs -Q -nw` and type <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>c</kbd><kbd>C-;</kbd>, do you get a `"C-; is undefined"` message?

Assuming that it is a terminal issue, here are some related Q&As which may point you in the right direction, but it's going to depend upon the particular terminal you are using.

- [Binding M-<up> / M-<down> in Emacs 23.1.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4351044/binding-m-up-m-down-in-emacs-23-1-1/4360658#4360658)
- [Send "C-(" to Emacs in VT100/xterm terminal (Mac OS X's Terminal)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4337837/send-c-to-emacs-in-vt100-xterm-terminal-mac-os-xs-terminal)
- [How does one send S-RET to Emacs in a terminal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3528713/how-does-one-send-s-ret-to-emacs-in-a-terminal)
- [emacs -nw issues with cscope and terminals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6026442/emacs-nw-issues-with-cscope-and-terminals)

Answer (score 5):

Indeed `C-;` is typically not something your terminal is able to send to an underlying application like Emacs (so it works under a GUI but not in a terminal).  But I wonder: why do you need such a binding anyway, given that `M-;` is already bound to `comment-dwim` which does comment/uncomment the region when the region is selected, so it provides a superset of `comment-or-uncomment-region`.